# GCDAsyncSocket readData not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, gcdasyncsocket

I'm trying to send a message to a server and receive a response using my iPhone. I can connect to the server using:

```
telnet 123.123.123.1 6000
Trying 123.123.123.1...
Connected to 123.123.123.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
?VERSION
OK
VERSION=PROTOCOL: 1.1.0
```

?VERSION is my question

OK states it received and understood the question

VERSION= is the response from the server

so I'm trying to do the same thing but with xcode

So I have this in my viewDidLoad

```
dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc]initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:mainQueue];
asyncSocket.delegate = self;

NSString *host = @"123.123.123.1";
uint16_t port = 6000;

NSLog(@"Connecting to \"%@\" on port %hu...", host, port);

NSError *error = nil;
if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:host onPort:port withTimeout:5.0 error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connecting...");
}
```

And I have the following code showing it connected

```
-(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:
(UInt16)port

{
NSLog(@"socket:%p didConnectToHost:%@ port:%hu", sock, host, port);

// We're just going to send a test string to the server.

NSString *myStr = @"?VERSION";
NSData *myData2 = [myStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[asyncSocket writeData:myData2 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];


}
```

And the following to show it wrote

```
-(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag{
NSLog(@"WRITING");
[asyncSocket readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket LFData] withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}
```

Sadly this never gets called

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{


NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data 
                                        encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];


}
```

I'm lost and really need some assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you say write AND read at the same time. First call `[asyncSocket writeData:myData2 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];` and in `didWriteDataWithTag` call `[asyncSocket readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket LFData] withTimeout:-1 tag:0];`. You are on one thread - `dispatch_get_main_queue()` - it can't do two things at one time.

Comment: I changed it in my post, I originally tried it this way and it did not work so I was trying different approaches. I'm still unable to receive anything from the server. Any suggestions other than your original suggestion?

Comment: Try this instead `[asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];`

Comment: Still no response sadly. I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now. Can we assume that because it works using "Terminal" with telnet, that the communication is working correctly between client/server.

Comment: Hm hm, I'm thinking - the protocol itself tells you that the escape character is `'^]'`. Then you're sending only `?VERSION`. I believe that should be "escaped". Because it looks like the protocol thinks you're still writing because it didn't receive the escaping character.

Comment: You are correct I can do the following from "Terminal"  
?VERSION
OK
VERSION=PROTOCOL: 1.1.0
?VERSION
OK
VERSION=PROTOCOL: 1.1.0
Sorry about the format, but I can continue calling ?VERSION or whatever else I want to. The protocol will continue thinking I'm writing until I do '^]'.

Comment: Well then try to send it from the app with the escaping character so the server knows that you're "done" writing data. Then you should receive a response.

Comment: I did the following
char bytes[] = "?VERSION";
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
    
[asyncSocket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    
char bytes2[] = "^]";
NSData* data2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes2)];
    
[asyncSocket writeData:data2 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];

It called didWriteDataWithTag twice, but never called didReadData

Comment: Should I be sending the server data? Or should I be sending it bytes? No idea if that matters for what we are talking about.

Comment: Try appending it and encode it to NSData as "?VERSION^]", because if you send it separately, it can send the escaping character before the "?VERSION". And use internal method of NSData - `[@"?VERSION^]" dataUsingEncoding:...]`

Comment: NSString *myStr = @"?VERSION^]";
NSData *data = [myStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
[asyncSocket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];

I did this and still no response. You'd think I'd get some error response or something. Sorry that this is not working like it should.

Comment: I got it to work, sorry Michal you were on the right track, I just didn't give you the right information. I needed to send it the new line feed so ?VERSION\n

Comment: There you go! I am happy you solved it. Take it easy :)